# Can I use the rotate function to move a line around the clock?

Tags: javascript, object, rotation

I have an object. It draws a line. I would like to move it by a certain angle, around a certain point. Can I use the rotate function?

```
function bigHand(){
this.fx=50;
this.fy=50;
this.tx=10;
this.ty=50;
drawLine(fx,fy,tx,ty);
}
bigHand().rotate(30,50,50);
```

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about canvas functions, you would:

- save the canvas state
- translate the canvas to your origin (start point of the line/center of the clock)
- rotate the canvas
- draw your line
- restore the canvas state

That also implies you're redrawing that entire section of the canvas for each frame of your animated clock. Alternatively, you could calculate the new end point of your rotated line and redraw it, no rotation or translation necessary.

If you specified what it is you're using (canvas, some arbitrary library, magic) it would help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am using a canvas. I meant to ask how to use this rotate function on an object. Let say, like this?

```
function bigHand(){
this.fx=50;
this.fy=50;
this.tx=10;
this.ty=50;
drawLine(fx,fy,tx,ty);
}
var bigHandObj=new bigHand();
```

Comment: bigHandObj.rotate(30);